# I want to create football pitch in flutter how can i achive it without using stack and putting players on it

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, visual-studio-code

[image: football pitch image]

I already created putting image and put players on it but this is not responsive may be one team has the formation of 4-3-3 and the other team has 3-4-2-1 so this means one side is larger than the other in terms of height

I want something as shown in below picture:

[image: fotmob image pitch]

Answer (score 0):

1. if u want ur player in a static linear line then this code will do

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FootballScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/football-screen';
  const FootballScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<FootballScreen> createState() => _FootballScreenState();
}

class _FootballScreenState extends State<FootballScreen> {
  // for formation 3-4-2-1,
  List<int> players = [3, 4, 2, 1];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / (players.length + 1);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/pitch.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: players.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(height: size, child: _child(index));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _child(int index) {
    // goalkie
    if (index == 0) {
      return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: _playerImg('assets/2.jpg'));
    }
    // formated players
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: List.generate(
        players[index - 1],
        (index) => _playerImg('assets/2.jpg'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _playerImg(String img) =>
      CircleAvatar(radius: 30, backgroundImage: AssetImage(img));
}
```

[result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PqZDy9amqQZQB-4NFCDonE2P5hJgkvrp/view?usp=share_link)
2. if u want ur player in dynamic position on the row then **u must use Stack to solidify

Comment: I mentioned above this will leads to have problem with responsiveness

Comment: updated it with full code.